# Are there frameworks available for geolocation polygon coordinates down to the town level?

Tags: swift, geolocation, mapbox

I'm currently using Mapbox but I've yet to find a way to draw polygon regions programmatically with coordinates that come as part of the Mapbox SDK. For instance if I want to outline the boundaries of Houston, TX as seen in the image below. Does Mapbox have a coordinate library that comes with the SDK? If so, how is it accessed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, support for this isn't there, but you can find any other source of region data like this (say from http://www.naturalearthdata.com or Wikipedia) and add it as annotations, which are very performant in the 2.x version of the SDK.